# react-native-maps not loaded fully

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I have used [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps) in my project. But, after I zoom out or navigate inside the map, the map turns blank as shown in the figure as it is not loading. What would be the solution?

Here is the code snippet :

```
<MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={initialOrigin}
        onRegionChangeComplete={initialOriginChangeHandler}>
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: initialOrigin.latitude,
            longitude: initialOrigin.longitude,
          }}
        />
      </MapView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, avoid restricting your google API on https://console.cloud.google.com/ for now.
Secondly, add `flex:1; height:400; width:400` to your MapView from `react-native-maps`.